# How to save a topic model in R and run it on different data

Tags: r, lda

I am fairly new to topic models. I have two corpora of documents and want to compare how often the same topics occur in the different corpora.  I ran a topic model with 40 topics on a combined sample of documents of both corpora. I now want to save the model and run it seperately for the two corpora. I am using the topic models package and thought I had to fill in save = 1 (See below), but am not sure. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
control_LDA_VEM <-
+    list(estimate.alpha = TRUE, alpha = 50/k, estimate.beta = TRUE,
+         verbose = 0, prefix = tempfile(), save = 1, keep = 0,
+         seed = as.integer(Sys.time()), nstart = 1, best = TRUE,
+         var = list(iter.max = 500, tol = 10^-6),
+         em = list(iter.max = 1000, tol = 10^-4),
+         initialize = "random")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `save` parameter is actually used to save/not save intermediate results, using the `prefix` parameter to set the location to store the results (`tempfile()` generates a system location for you).

To use a saved LDA model, you can merely use the name of the model in your next `LDA()` call. You can also change the control parameters using the call, as well. Assuming you divided the desired DTM into training and test sets, this is the idea:

```
lda.train <- LDA(train, k = 10, control = control_LDA_VEM)
lda.test <- LDA(test, model=lda.train, control = list(estimate.beta = FALSE)
```

This [link](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2408&context=commpapers) might be of use to you.